# Where would I draw CGPaths in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

Usually you would use a custom view and the `draw(rect:`) method within in it to draw paths but since I don't have `UIView`s (and don't want to use `UIKit` integration) where can I draw?

Comment: Have you seen the [Drawing Paths and Shapes tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/drawing-paths-and-shapes)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use the `GeometryReader` and the `Path`

```
return GeometryReader { geometry in
    Path { path in
        path.addPath(...)
    }
}
```

[Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryreader)

And a [Swift Tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/drawing-paths-and-shapes) on that topic also by Apple